# jq - two depth field combile with slash

Tags: jq

I have a matrix in json format as below.

```
{
    "cpuUtilization": {
        "guest": 0,
        "irq": 0,
        "system": 1.7,
        "wait": 0.1,
        "idle": 86.6,
        "user": 4.2,
        "total": 13.4,
        "steal": 5,
        "nice": 2.4
    },
    "loadAverageMinute": {
        "one": 0.65,
        "five": 0.63,
        "fifteen": 0.5
    },
    "memory": {
        "writeback": 0,
        "hugePagesFree": 1,
        "hugePagesRsvd": 0,
        "hugePagesSurp": 0,
        "cached": 216624,
        "hugePagesSize": 2048,
        "free": 116764,
        "hugePagesTotal": 325,
        "inactive": 478084,
        "pageTables": 6508,
        "dirty": 620,
        "mapped": 57336,
        "active": 649440,
        "total": 2014212,
        "slab": 48984,
        "buffers": 67976
    }
}
```

I want to get only cpuUtilization and memory.
And the form is:

```
cpuUtilization\guest = 0
cpuUtilization\irq = 0
...
cpuUtilization\nice = 2.4
memory\writeback = 0
memory\hugePagesFree = 1
...
```

I'm trying to make one using the map option, and would like some help from someone who knows better.

Comment: Just use two nested for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution, first updating your inner keys, then streaming all entries:

```
{ cpuUtilization, memory }
| with_entries(.key as $key | .value = (.value | with_entries(.key |= "\($key)\\\(.)")))
| .[]
| to_entries[]
| "\(.key) = \(.value)"
```

Alternatively, directly stream the outer and inner entries:

```
{ cpuUtilization, memory }
| to_entries[]
| .key as $key
| .value
| to_entries[]
| "\($key)\\\(.key) = \(.value)"
```

or build objects with "group", "key", and "value" properties, then convert those to strings:

```
{ cpuUtilization, memory }
| to_entries[]
| { group: .key } + (.value | to_entries[])
| "\(.group)\\\(.key) = \(.value)"
```

Output with `-r`/`--raw-output`:

```
...
cpuUtilization\steal = 5
cpuUtilization\nice = 2.4
memory\writeback = 0
memory\hugePagesFree = 1
...
```

Comment: hehe.  I was doing this. ```/usr/local/bin/jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)"'```
 ```/usr/local/bin/jq -r '.cpuUtilization as $k | "\($k)" , .memory as $k | "\($k)"'```
 ```/usr/local/bin/jq -r '.cpuUtilization, .memory | to_entries | map(join(" = "))'```
 ```/usr/local/bin/jq -r '. | to_entries '```

The direction would have changed a lot. thank you for telling me.
I only made a small correction. ```to_entries[] | select (.key == "cpuUtilization" or .key == "memory") | .key as $key ..```

Comment: @P.Lonnie sorry, I missed the bit about only including two keys. There's a simpler way than selecting based on the entries. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple nested loop using `keys_unsorted`:

```bash
keys_unsorted[] as $lev1 | .[$lev1]
| keys_unsorted[] as $lev2 | .[$lev2]
  | $lev1 + "\\" + $lev2 + " = \(.)"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_REylJt4X3_K)

If you want the list to be sorted, use `keys` instead of `keys_unsorted`.

---

For an arbitrary depth, you can use `paths` and `getpath`:

```bash
paths(scalars) as $p | ($p | join("\\")) + "= \(getpath($p))"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mjg52HJINLr)

Or use `tostream` which already provides all parts in arrays:

```bash
tostream | select(has(1)) | first |= join("\\") | join(" = ")
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eqh5_ocoJb8)

Comment: Wow, the `paths` based solution is pretty neat!

Comment: In the FP paradigm, the more general approaches are often the simpler ones.